# How to override ciphers/protocols programatically on JAX-RS client

Tags: ssl, jersey, jax-rs, tls1.2, handshake

I'm facing issue while trying to override ciphers/protocols on JAX-RS client.   Jersey framework is used here.

Following is the way client is built.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier).build();
```

I have tried following approaches, but couldn't succeed.

1. Created Custom `SSLSocketFactory`, and override ciphers and protocols on `createSocket()` method of `SSL SocketFactory` class. 
   Then, `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sf)`.
   But, its not reflected with this approach.
2. Tried overriding the `sslcontext` with help of `SslContextFactory` & `SSLParameters`, which also could help.

Could someone help in finding a way to override ciphers/protocols programatically on `sslContext` of JAX-RS client?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an SSLSocketFactory :

```
public class CustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;

    public CustomSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) {
        this.sslSocketFactory = sslSocketFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return sslSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return adjustEnabledCipherSuites((SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return adjustEnabledCipherSuites((SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        return adjustEnabledCipherSuites((SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return adjustEnabledCipherSuites((SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return adjustEnabledCipherSuites((SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return adjustEnabledCipherSuites((SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private SSLSocket adjustEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocket sslSocket) {
        sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"});
        return sslSocket;
    }
}
```

Now you need to configure your client to use a custom ConnectionFactory that uses the above SSLSocketFactory :

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig()
CustomSSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

 HttpUrlConnectorProvider.ConnectionFactory factory = url -> {
     HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
     return httpsURLConnection;
 };
 clientConfig.connectorProvider(new HttpUrlConnectorProvider().connectionFactory(factory));
```

...

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier).withConfig(clientConfig).build();
```